# How do I respond to edits?

Tags: discussion, support, editing

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [Minimum losses to eliminate you from top 2 in round robin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4884180/minimum-losses-to-eliminate-you-from-top-2-in-round-robin/4884197#4884197)

Someone asked a question about round robin. I answered. He then realized that he didn't specify something, so he edited the question. when I edited the answer to fit the question, the site said not to change the meaning and not to respond to the one that asked the question with an edit. I edited the answer to fit the question anyways. Is that what I was supposed to do? Or something else?

Comment: Wait – the site told you not to edit your own answer?

Comment: no, It told me that I am not supposed to reply to the asker using an edit, and that edits are only used to clarify intent

Comment: OK, then, I think you did the right thing in editing your answer. I haven't looked at the link – did you indicate in your edit that you were editing in response to a change in the question? That probably wouldn't have changed the system's response, but it might have clarified matters to other users who might wonder why you made your edit.

Comment: Thank you gerry, that is a good enough answer